# Cucumber/Capybara + Angular: Test passes using selenium driver, but not poltergeist

Tags: angularjs, selenium, cucumber, capybara, poltergeist

I am trying to run feature tests on an angular app, but they keep failing using poltergeist driver. The reason seems to be because data-binding syntax was being used literally. For example, under poltergeist, for the following link, where {{userName}} would be displayed as 'User Name',

```
<a href="/path/to/somewhere">{{userName}}</a>
```

`find(:link, text: 'User Name').click` fails, but `find(:link, text: '{{userName}}').click` works.

Under selenium driver, `find(:link, text: 'User Name').click` works fine.

I would like to use poltergeist so that I can run them as a part of entire test suite and incorporated into CI, and this is preventing it.

The following is Cucumber setup in env.rb.

```
require 'cucumber/rails'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist_debug do |app|
  options = { inspector: true, js_errors: false, timeout: 180, phantomjs_options: ['--load-images=no', '--ignore-ssl-errors=yes'] }

  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, options)
end

Capybara.default_wait_time = 30
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist_debug
Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist_debug

DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
DatabaseCleaner.clean

Cucumber::Rails::Database.javascript_strategy = :truncation
```

Any help would be much, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could give this gem a go:
https://github.com/kikonen/capybara-ng